# Show that $||f-\bar{f}||_{L^1}\leq 2||f(x)x(1-x)||_{L^1}$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

So I'm just trying some PDE problems. Let $f(x)\in W^{1,1}([0,1])$. Let $\bar{f}=\int_0^1f(x)dx$. Show that

$$||f-\bar{f}||_{L^1}\leq 2||f(x)x(1-x)||_{L^1}$$

What I have tried so far is

$$\begin{align}f(x)-\bar{f}&=f(x)-\int_0^1f(y)dy\\
&=\int_0^1f(x)-f(y)dy\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{2}dx\\
\end{align}$$

Any suggestions on how I can get the $x(1-x)$ factor into the equations?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken when $f(x)=x$ then the left side of your inequality is $\frac{1}{4}$ but the right hand side is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: There is no such inequality. False alarm.

Comment: Certainly the RHS must contain $f'$, and then the inequality becomes more plausible (also, if not, why assume that $f$ has a derivative?).

Comment: I just assumed that the derivative part was used in manipulating the integral. Namely, you can approximate the 1 function by test functions and do some differentiation to get the inequality. If we modify the problem do you think its possible to establish the result? Cause there was another problem from the place I got this from and it also wasn't provable(statement wasn't true).